# Excel: Calculate zero values and return date difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column A has dates `dd-mmmm-yyyy` Column B values range from 0 to x (numerical). How can I get all those cells where 0 values occur more than 7 times in column B? So for example:

```
Cells(B5) = 3 
cells(B6) = 0
Cells(B20) = 0
cells(B21) = 90
```

How can I get the count of zeros between Cells(B5) and cells(B21) and then calculate the date difference between Cells(B21) and cells(B3)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are the dates true dates and not text that look like date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(C2=0,C3>0,ROW() - MATCH(2,IF($C$2:C2<>0,1))>=8),A2-INDEX($A$2:A2,MATCH(2,IF($C$2:C2<>0,1))),""),"")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

So put the formula in D2, Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter then copy/drag Down.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response. I tried the formula but it also returned counts where number of zeros was less than seven

Comment: It should not. see edit to answer above for proof.   @TonyAnthony

Comment: I have it >=7 zeroes, do you want it only >7?  If so take out the `=` from the `>= 8`.  Also does your data start in row 2 if not then we will need to make some changes to the formula.

Comment: Thank you very much Scott. That did the trick. Thank you - really appreciate the help.

Comment: @TonyAnthony please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.